# Export Visual Studio Template error: "Unable to read an exported file"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-templates

When exporting a Visual Studio project to a Template (File/Export Template...) I get the following error upon clicking the **Finish** button:

```
    Unable to read an exported file for the following
    reason: The file cannot be opened with the selected 
    editor. Please choose another editor.
```

[Screenshot http://img687.yfrog.com/img687/1756/templateerror.png](http://img687.yfrog.com/img687/1756/templateerror.png)

A Google search for this error has only led to [several](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/4d71a5c7-3622-452b-b4ff-07983e8f9ae3) [dead](http://www.adras.com/Export-Template-Wizard.t12870-23.html) [ends](http://forums.asp.net/p/1508113/3592430.aspx). There aren't any unusual file types in this project. Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By laborious trial and error (start with an empty project, add a folder, try to export template) I was able to narrow this down to a single Javascript file. As it happens, it's one of the language definitions for  `prettify.js` (which is used on this site for code coloring). The file in question is `lang-hs.js`, and for some reason Windows on my machine treats this file differently from other Javascript files: It opens in Notepad, when I have the `.js` extension mapped to Visual Studio.

I'm not sure what the underlying explanation is, but I've already wasted enough time on this and I believe I can live without Haskell code coloring (!) so I'm just deleting this file and moving on.

Answer (score 3):

It seems ".cur" files are often a culprit in this error. I have removed them from my project and now the exportation works correctly.

Microsoft staff suggest looking at log files (../windows/system32/compmgmt.msc) but this error does not spawn an entry into the Application EventLog.

Comment: There were 2 .cur files in the project. Removing them indeed solved the problem!